# Argument 1 must be an instance of Drupal\tcdev\Controller\UserAuth, instance of Drupal\user\UserAuth given

Tags: users, 8

I want to programmatically log in a user with a custom controller. I want to pass my data with `$_POST` to the route (I pass data from a mobile application); if username and password are correct, the method/function should return `TRUE`.

The route is the following one.

```
tcdev.login:
  path: '/tclogin'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\tcdev\Controller\MYCenterController::login'
    _title: 'Login call back'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The code for the controller is the following one.

```
namespace  Drupal\tcdev\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyController extends ControllerBase {

    /**
     * \Drupal\user\UserAuth definition.
     *
     * @var \Drupal\user\UserAuth
     */
    protected $userAuth;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(UserAuth $user_auth) {
        $this->userAuth = $user_auth;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new static($container->get('user.auth'));
    }
    }

    public function login() {
        $uid = $this->userAuth->authenticate($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
        $acc = User::load($uid);

        //return new Response('Hi ' . $uid);
    }

}
```

It returns me the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to `Drupal\tcdev\Controller\MyController::__construct()` must be an instance of `Drupal\tcdev\Controller\UserAuth`, instance of `Drupal\user\UserAuth` given, called in /Users/yms/Sites/devdesktop/gttc/modules/tcdev/src/Controller/MyController.php on line 32 in `Drupal\tcdev\Controller\MyController::__construct()` (line 23 of modules/tcdev/src/Controller/MyController.php)

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing the *TypeError* you quoted is how you declare the arguments in the following method.

```
public function __construct(UserAuth $user_auth) {
  $this->userAuth = $user_auth;
}
```

Since you don't use any namespace for `UserAuth`, nor did you add `use \Drupal\user\UserAuth;` at the beginning of your code, PHP assumes the argument for the class constructor is an object of the `Drupal\tcdev\Controller\UserAuth` class because `Drupal\tcdev\Controller` is the namespace used from that file.
This is in conflict with the class of the object the constructor is actually receiving; that is why Drupal raises a `TypeError` exception.

Full-qualify the argument, or add the `use` line at the beginning of the file; either of them will fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the user.auth in your controller:

```
$auth = $container->get('user.auth')
```

[edited to clarify injection basics:

In public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) add $container->get('user.auth') to the return new static(...) statement.

In public function __construct(...) add the $auth to the signature at the correct position. Then add a private (or protected) variable $auth to your controller and assign the value from __construct to it.

You may simplify that by using drupal console or drush. They can create the boiler plate code for you.

If you don't want to use injection, you may use `$auth = \Drupal::service('user.auth');`

But this has drawbacks in testability.

[end edit]

then call the authenticate func:

```
$uid = $auth->authenticate($username, $pass);
```

With the $uid load the user:

```
$acc = User::load($uid);
```

Then set the user into the session:

```
  \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($acc);
  \Drupal::logger('user')->notice('Session opened for %name.', array('%name' => $acc->getUsername()));
```

Should work. But I don't think that it is a good idea to pass around the password in the URL of your tcdev.login...

Edit: Sample Code (generated by `drupal generate:controller`)

```
namespace Drupal\preosuser\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserAuth;

/**
 * Class AuthController.
 *
 * @package Drupal\preosuser\Controller
 */
class AuthController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Drupal\user\UserAuth definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\user\UserAuth
   */
  protected $userAuth;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(UserAuth $user_auth) {
    $this->userAuth = $user_auth;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('user.auth')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Checklogin.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Return Hello string.
   */
  public function CheckLogin($name) {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Implement method: CheckLogin with parameter(s): $name'),
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: and what is better solution? pass by $_POST ?

Comment: Yes, at least. You could also use the standard Drupal Form API for this, take a look at the UserLoginTest Class for details.

Comment: tnx,  I use `$container =  Drupal::getContainer();` to get contatiner but face with `Error: Class 'Drupal\tcdev\Controller\Drupal' not found in Drupal\tcdev\C`.

Comment: can you tell me how can I get Container?

Comment: You need to do this in the constructor of your Controller. This is injection basics, take a look at any other controller. I modify my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: can you give a link?

Comment: Sure, for example this one: https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-dependency-injection

Comment: can you please complete your code with my login method in my controller? I don't find out how can I pass Contanier to my method

Comment: what I should pass to controller?

Comment: Should be $container = \Drupal::getContainer(); The slash before 'Drupal'.

Comment: Yes, there's a "\" missing in the declaration. Please stop this now, it's basic php programming.

Comment: Actually, this question doesn't explain the error message the OP is getting, and the code shown here contains the same error the code used by the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use mistake annotation and you have to pass right arguments to your constructor.

add `use Drupal\User\UserAuth;` and then try

```
/**
 * \Drupal\user\UserAuth definition.
 *
 * @var UserAuth
 */
protected $userAuth;

/**
 * Constructs .
 *
 * @param UserAuth $user_auth
 *
 */
public function __construct(UserAuth $user_auth) {
    $this->userAuth = $user_auth;
}
```